# WebSocket Client as an always running service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, websockets, iis

The company with which we are integrating is a door security company that makes RFID cards and door scanners. You scan your card, the door opens and lets you in. They allow 3rd party integration via their websocket server. They post "Events" to their server. "Bob Foobar scanned his card at door reader #14 at 8:12am on 2/26/2018" all in json format. We need to constantly listen for all of those events and log them in our database.

We give our clients two options. We cloud host our service in a multi tenant SAAS environment. But we also allow customers to self-host if they want. If we only had the SAAS option, then this would be a simple solution. Just create a Windows Service that runs on our servers to subscribe to their websocket server. But, for our self-hosted customers, we are hoping to avoid asking them to install a Windows Service. We are looking for other ways to make this happen. But, we also don't want to ask them to open a browser window and keep it open.

I need to subscribe to a remote websocket, and I need to do it in such a way that it's always listening, even w/o user interaction. This isn't a chat type service that is user-centric. We need to always be listening for events as they appear on the remote server.

I've been reading up on System.Net.WebSockets, and I've seen lots of examples. I have built a proof-of-concept as a Windows Service, and it works.

But... is a Windows Service really the only way to always subscribe to the remote websocket server w/o user interaction? What other options do I have? And, is it possible to accomplish this strictly using IIS?

Comment: Down-votes w/o an explanation are so frustrating.  Can't you at least take 20 seconds to teach and explain?

Comment: I'm guessing because it appears to be an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: It's also unclear why you need user interaction to connect a websocket.  Most systems are unaware of eyeballs.  What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: @JimmyJames, the vast majority of tutorials I see on websockets teach how to wet up a web-based chat service. That's not what I want.  I need a userless subscription to a websocket server that listens for events w/o having a web page loaded in a browser.

Comment: So where do you want this to run and what's the point of it?

Comment: @VincentSavard, that's just it. This needs to happen without a human user.  The company which hosts the web socket server will post events, and we need to receive them... all without any humans and without a browser being opened.  Again, I got this to work in a Windows Service. The service runs and it grabs events and logs them to our DB just fine. I am just hoping to find a way to do the same thing, but without a Windows Service.

Comment: It needs to run somewhere.  What options do you have available to you?

Comment: Why don't you want a Windows Service?

Comment: I honestly don't understand your point about "humans". Why would you need a human to run a piece of software? Can you tell us exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Also, do you have to use websockets?  For this kind of thing, I would recommend a simple GET type interaction.

Comment: @JimmyJames:  More info.... the company with which we are integrating is a door security company that makes RFID cards and door scanners.  You scan your card, the door opens and lets you in.  They allow 3rd party integration via their websocket server.  They post "Events" to their server.  "Bob Foobar scanned his card at door reader #14 at 8:12am on 2/26/2018" all in json format.  We need to constantly be listening for those events and logging them in our database, and we need to do it without a browser window being open.  (more in the next comment...)

Comment: On our end, we give our clients two options.  We cloud host our service in a multi tenant SAAS environment. But we also allow customers to self-host if they want.  If we only had the SASS option, then this would be a simple solution.  Just create a Windows Service that runs on our servers to subscribe to their websocket server.  But, for our self-hosted customers, we are hoping to avoid asking them to install a Windows Service.  We are looking for other ways to make this happen.  But, we also don't want to ask them to open a browser window and keep it open.  So.... is their a third option?

Comment: Yes, sadly, websockets is the only option this particular company provides.

Comment: All of that should go in the question.  That should get rid of the downvote and get you some help.

Comment: Why don't you connect to this websocket directly in your SaaS? Do you absolutely want another process running along your SaaS?

Comment: @VincentSavard, that would work if all of our clients were using the SAAS option. But roughly half are self hosted.

Comment: @JimmyJames, I was trying to keep the question as simple as possible to avoid a lot of extra reading. But, I appreciate you being persistent!!

Comment: At the risk of getting off-topic, why don't you want to ask them to install a service? And do you want to let the customer run the software on a machine, which may be running without any local/interactive user even logged in (i.e. some kind of server machine, like a web server or file server or domain server oslt)?

Comment: I wasn't clear, sorry. What I meant is why don't the software your users already self-host connect to this websocket? Why do you need a separate process?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 3 or 4 kinds of process:

- Applications started by a user
- Applications started automatically when a user logs in
- Services started when the O/S boots, before the user logs in
- (Device drivers)

If you want your process to run:

- Before a user logs in
- and after a user logs in
- and after a user logs out

... then it does need to be running as a ("system") service, instead of as a ("user") application.

Alternatives:

- Run it as a plug-in of an existing service -- in that case, the architecture and administration (e.g. installation) of the plug-in, and its security context, depends on the service (e.g. IIS)
- Run it as a user application, if you don't mind the user being able to kill it and you don't mind it starting and stopping when the user logs in or out

Comment: ..or you can write your own system service

Comment: Yes, when I said "alternatives" I meant "alternatives to the aforementioned running it as a service".

Comment: i must be getting old and sleepy

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see with either the SAAS solution or the client-based solution is how you deal with disconnects.  I'm not a websockets expert (far from it) but I don't believe there is anything built in to it to maintain a subscription.  I could be wrong but a cursory search didn't turn up anything.  If you truly need to capture every message, this is a big issue as you must expect some downtime of either your client and/or the network.  Have you considered how you will catch-up on missed messages?  When I played around with these a bit, I found that connections were not terribly stable and would drop unexpectedly (it was a while ago: YMMV.)  You, will, at the very least need to make sure your client can re-establish itself if you lose the connection.

As far as running it goes, you just need to create a client application.  I would provide that to your customers and give them information on how to run it as a service in windows.  The whole thing sounds rather flimsy though.  Not so much because what you are trying to do but because you have to depend on websockets.  I think they can be useful if combined with a proper API that allows you to retrieve information on demand but by themselves, I think you will have issues.

Comment: I guess you're referring to https://www.google.fr/search?q=run+application+as+service using a non-standard (third-party) service control manager.

Comment: @ChrisW I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  Can you clarify?

Comment: You wrote, "create a client application ... provide that to your customers and give them information on how to run it as a service in windows". SFAIK you can't run a client application as a service (a service must implement [ServiceMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). But 3rd-party s/w may let you do it ... or (googling) I find [srvany](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) ... I guess I'm asking, "what exactly are you suggesting, re. information on how to run it as a service?"

Comment: The whole topic is kind of kind of moot though if the OP doesn't want a service and won't say why.

Comment: @ChrisW Honestly, I would never run something that needs to be up all the time in windows.  I assumed any commandline process could be run as a service like how a daemon in *nix.  I'm probably wrong here, I'll edit the answer later.